# Modifying an attribute of an object created by a builder class

Tags: java, builder

There is an already existing class, a pojo with a nested static builder class. There are two components in the project.

Component A sends the ObjectX after building it using the builder. Component B receives it and uses its attributes for calculation throughout its life cycle in component B.

My problem is there is a requirement to change an attribute of ObjectX inside component B.

Can't be done before using the builder method since building is happening in component A. Since it's not the practice to have setter methods for an object created by a builder design pattern what would be the approach to solve this issue. 
FYI model for the object x lies within the component B. Since component A will have component B code available through Jars in deployment ObjectX model can be changed to get it done. I'm just wondering that if it's the the right way to do this.

```
class ComponentA{


   CallingMethodofComponenentB( new objectXBuilder().setName("B).setAge(5).build());

}
```

---

```
class ComponenetB {

receivingObjectXMethod(ObjectX x){

   println(x.getName() + x.getAge());
}

Class ObjectX{

    private ObjectX(ObjectXBuilder builder){
        this.name = builder.getName();
        this.age = builder.getAge();
    }

// Getters ...

public static class ObjectXBuilder{

    private String name;
    private int age

    // Setters ...


    ObjectXBuilder(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    ObjectX build(){
        return new ObjectX(this);
    }
}
```

---

The requirement is to change the age depending on a logic in component B side. That should be done inside builder class or should there be a setter for ObjectX?

Comment: ¯\(°_o)/¯ There's no general answer to this question; it just depends. I'm not aware of anything saying builder-built classes can't have setter methods--builders are for convenience and/or to prevent instantiation errors. That doesn't mean they're not allowed to change after they're built. Which makes "more" sense depends on your architectural leeway and your application.

Comment: If you want to keep your object immutable, you can always have a withAge(int newAge) method which creates a copy of the object with the new age.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a class specific to B, call it `ObjectXForB` that you could use to compose in a `ObjectX` field.
In this way, you could define in `ObjectXForB` the computed value of age.

For example you could create the object in this way:

```
ObjectXForB objectXForB = new ObjectXForB(objectX);
```

With a ObjectXForB class :

```
public class ObjectXForB{
   private ObjectX objectX;
   private int age;

   public ObjectXForB(ObjectX objectX){
      this.objectX = objectX;
       // logic to get a new value of age if required
       ... 
       age = ...;
   }


   public int getAge(){
       return age;
   }

   // raw view methods on the ObjectX component
    public String getName(){
       return objectX.getName();
   }
}
```

If you can introduce a common interface between the classes 
ObjectX and ObjectXForB, it would be probably better as you could declare variable with `ObjectX` type instead of `ObjectXForB`. It allows to change the implementation if it becomes suitable.

Comment: you are meaning that since then the age becomes an object so it can be changed without setters?

Comment: So then when in the fututre if name also want to be changed then you'd have to create another object which includes all three? doesn't sound like a good approach

Comment: I updated to give a sample code. The idea is to have an object that provides the abstraction and the adaptability to your need without changing ObjectX.

Comment: No you need to have a single composite object.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method `copyOf(ObjectX)` to `ObjectXBuilder` to be able to initialize the builder with an existing object.

```
ObjectX other = new ObjectXBuilder().copyOf(objectX).setAge(42).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be mixing the concepts of immutables and builders.

If you want to change the attributes of an immutable, you could create a class that wraps the creation of a new immutable, using some of the original immutable's attributes.

```
class ObjectXChanger {
    String name;
    int age;

    public ObjectXChanger(ObjectX objectX) {
        this.name = objectX.getName();
        this.age = objectX.age();
    }

    public void changeName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void changeAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public ObjectX getModifiedObjectX() {
        // If your builder is static, there should be no need to 
        // create a new builder each time you want a new ObjectX.
        // This line should be ObjectXBuilder.build(this.name, this.age);
        return (new ObjectXBuilder(this.name, this.age).build());
    }
}
// In your usage of ObjectX in Component B
class ComponenetB {

receivingObjectXMethod(ObjectX x){
    // If we want to change based on age
    if(x.getAge() > 10) {
         // pun intended
         ObjectXChanger xChanger = new ObjectXChanger(x);
         // Modifies the age here
         xChanger.changeAge(20);
         // x now is a reference to the new ObjectX
         x = xChanger.getModifiedObjectX;
    } 
    println(x.getName() + x.getAge());
}
```